# OpenSCAP Workbench customize Datastream Files

Tags: openscap

When i try to tailoring this datastream file, i get following error:

Opened file '/Applications/scap-workbench.app/Contents/Resources/ssg/ssg-rhel7-ds.xml'.

Error while opening file.

There was a problem with ScanningSession!
Failed to reload session. OpenSCAP error message:
Could not extract scap_org.open-scap_cref_ssg-rhel7-xccdf-1.2.xml with all dependencies from datastream. [ds_sds_session.c:211]

I have this Version:
SCAP Workbench 1.1.5, compiled with Qt 4.8.7, using OpenSCAP 1.3.0

Is it possible at all to customize datastream files? Can somone help me?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this new draft build of SCAP-Workbench for Mac built with newer version of OpenSCAP: https://github.com/OpenSCAP/scap-workbench/pull/302#issuecomment-1437047689